# Pascal: Const Array Of Const

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I am getting an 'Illegal Expression' error when creating a const char array of const chars.

```
Program Foo; (*excerpt*)
Const
  X : Char = 'X';
  O : Char = 'O';
  P : Array [1..2] of Char = (X,O);
Begin
  (*stuff*)
End.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm typing this from a device that doesn't have pascal. So I can't verify it, but this probably works:

```
Const 
X = 'x';
O = 'o';
P : array[1..2] of char = (o,x);
```

Comment: The language is case-insensitive. You wrote the same thing I already have.

Comment: No, i didn't specify the type of the constants, which makes a difference. Just try it, and let me know if it works.

Comment: Oh, got you. I actually did make `X` and `O` typeless before, but I wanted to know why giving them types causes an error.

Comment: Correct. This is because a typed constant is more like an initialzed var.

Answer (score 2):

You could also have written

```
Const
 X : Char = 'X';
 O : Char = 'O';
 P : Array [1..2] of Char = ('X', 'O');
```

to achieve the same effect